# How to get string list from data frame column which are not repeating in other column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have pandas DataFrame like this:

```
feature name 1  feature name 2
0   A            B
1   A            B 
2   A            C 
3   B            C 
4   B            D
```

And I want to get a list of "features name 2" without names which occurring in "feature name 1"
So desired output would look like this:

```
list = [C,D]
```

since B is occurring in first column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
mask = df['feature name 2'].isin(df['feature name 1'])
L = df.loc[~mask, 'feature name 2'].unique().tolist()
```

Or [`numpy.setdiff1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html):

```
L = np.setdiff1d(df['feature name 2'], df['feature name 1']).tolist()
print (L)
['C', 'D']
```